# jquery syntax - what's the difference between "[[" and "[{"

Tags: json, lua, datatables

I have a jquery table that is expecting data in this format:

```
  {
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [
        [
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "System Architect",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09",
            "$2,875"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton",
            "Cox",
            "Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "12th Jan 09",
            "$4,800"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm using a lua json library and when it encode my data, I get the following:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [
        {
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "System Architect",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09",
            "$2,875"
        },
        {
            "Ashton",
            "Cox",
            "Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "12th Jan 09",
            "$4,800"
        }
    ]
}
```

The only differences is in the use of curly brackets for each record, instead of square brackets.  When the jquery dataTable sees the curly braces, it dies.

I have two questions: 
1. what's the difference between the two? 
2. how can i encode my data with the square bracket instead of curly?

Comment: `[` is for arrays, `{` is for objects.

Comment: And `[{` and `[[` are just nested arrays/objects and not special syntax.

Comment: The JSON from Lua is invalid. `{ }` is for objects, and the contents have to be in the form `"property": value`.

Comment: i understand that when you nest, you have to double up.  i didn't know that "[" is for arrays and the other for objects.  @MarcB any comments on my second question?

Comment: @Barmar ah ok.  i think i'm getting a clearer picture...

Comment: @Barmar, if you post as an answer, I will accept it and then this question can be closed...

Comment: The only useful answer would be one that shows how to fix the Lua code so it produces valid JSON. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What lua json library is this? It has incorrectly detected the type of table being serialized in that inner spot.

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: You can file a bug report to whichever library you are currently using. The lua output of JSON is invalid.